# Is it possible to inject HttpSession object in each view JTwig and Spring MVC

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, controller, jtwig

I am using **SpringMVC** with **JTwig** view system and I want to be able to access the session scope (**HttpSession**) from all my views ( to know if I have to display the logout link for exemple ).

Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is supported by Jtwig natively. As per [Jtwig documentation](http://jtwig.org/documentation/reference/web/servlet) you can do the following:

```
{% if ((app.request.session.attributeName) is defined) %}
Hello
{% endif %}
```

To print `Hello` if the session attribute `attributeName` exists.